# about Multi-Dimensional array

Tags: data-structures, multidimensional-array

what is multidimensional array?
Multidimensional arrays can be described as "arrays of arrays". 
For example, a twoDMatrix array can be imagined as a twoDMatrix table made of elements, all of them of a same uniform data type.

```
int twoDMatrix [2 ][3 ]  =   {  {5,3,2},{8,4,1} };
```

I want to know this answer is correct or not .

Comment: This can easily be tested by running the code yourself. That's even easier than asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES dude, your representation is correct.

In the case of array access,

```
int twoDMatrix [2 ][3 ]  =   {  {5,3,2},{8,4,1} };

twoDMatrix[0][0] is 5 and twoDMatrix [1][1] is 4.
```

believe you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you mean is true. Multidimensional arrays are in fact *arrays of arrays* which can be visualized in memory as below,

```
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 1 |
```

Which is same as,

```
int twoDMatrix [2 ][3]  =   {{5,3,2}, {8,4,1}};
```

equivalent to,

```
int twoDMatrix [6]  =   { 5,3,2,8,4,1 };
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a 2d array its best to think of it as a grid where the first number represents column and the second represents row much like the data you would see in an excel table. At least that's what I do. Anything larger than a 3d array (think of a cube) becomes very confusing and possibly could be substituted with a different structure.